# Google cloud storage(GCS) Check past version's uploaded datetime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When Bucket versioning is enabled, we can get all versions of a file by typing

```
gsutil ls -a gs://path/to/file
```

However, It only shows the original file name and generation number...
Is there a way to see when those files were uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that using the following command:

> gsutil ls -a -L gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME]

As specified in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list), using the `-a` flag will list both live and noncurrent versions of the specified object. The `-L` flag will provide additional information about this object, containing the `Creation time` of the object.

If there's too much information shown using the previous command, the following command will show only the filename (along with the generation number) and the creation time:

> gsutil ls -a -L gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] | grep 'gs://\|Creation time'